# Why doesn't EMPTY complete the observable?

Tags: rxjs

In the code below, I am conditionally switching to another observable. If the condition is met it works fine. If the condition is not met and I return EMPTY from switchMap, the code in the subscribe block is not executed.

If I change `return EMPTY` to `return of(x)` it works.

```
   this.claimStoreService.setProducts(this.claim.products)
  .pipe(switchMap(x => {
    if (this.incomeEligibility) {
      return this.claimStoreService.saveIncomeEligibility();
    } else {
      return EMPTY;
    }
  }))
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.isSaving = false;
    this.goIntoDisplayMode();
  }, () => {
    this.isSaving = false;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the third callback:

```js
this.claimStoreService.setProducts(this.claim.products)
  .pipe(switchMap(x => {
    if (this.incomeEligibility) {
      return this.claimStoreService.saveIncomeEligibility();
    } else {
      return EMPTY;
    }
  }))
  .subscribe(
    () => this.goIntoDisplayMode(),
    console.err, 
    () => this.isSaving = false,
  );
```

Comment: Okay, that works and now I see that EMPTY completes but the success callback is not called. https://blog.novanet.no/rxjs-getting-fooled-by-empty-observables/

Comment: nice, glad to have helped

Comment: @Jamie Ide: that is a very informative post, thanks for sharing. So did you fix your problem by moving the isSaving to the finalize block

Comment: @Dwaraka I ended up using return of(x).

Answer (score 1):

It is probably more clear if you pass to the `subscribe` function an Observer. Your code would become

```
this.claimStoreService.setProducts(this.claim.products)
  .pipe(switchMap(x => {
    if (this.incomeEligibility) {
      return this.claimStoreService.saveIncomeEligibility();
    } else {
      return EMPTY;
    }
  }))
  .subscribe({
    next: () => this.goIntoDisplayMode(),
    error: err => console.error(err), 
    complete: () => this.isSaving = false,
  });
```